# Is it possible to use Jest testEnvironmentOptions to change initial JSDOM HTML?

Tags: jestjs, enzyme, jsdom

In Jest I'd like to change the initial JSDOM HTML from

```
<head></head><body></body>
```

to

```
<head></head><body><div id="app"></div></body>
```

in order to use [enzymes mount](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/mount.md#mountnode-options--reactwrapper) with the `attachTo` option.

I understand that [`testEnvironmentOptions`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#testenvironmentoptions-object) can be used to pass options to [JSDOM](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom#simple-options). Is there a field for the HTML?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can update your Jest config as follow

```js
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  testEnvironmentOptions: {
    html: '<!DOCTYPE html><div id="app"></div></html>',
  },
}
```

Reference: https://handbook.hung.dev/blog/customize-html-jest

Answer (score 0):

According to [jest source](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/packages/jest-environment-jsdom/src/index.js#L27) seems that this is not possible using `testEnvironmentOptions`.

You can extend `JSDOMEnvironment` (see [here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/packages/jest-environment-jsdom/src/index.js#L19)) and implement your own dom. But, I think you're going in the wrong direction. You shouldn't have problems using mount and attachTo without having the div via jsdom from start.

Something like:

```
wrapper = mount(
  <App/>, {attachTo: document.createElement('div')}
);
```

EDIT:

Extending `JSDOMEnvironment` should look something like this: (you should point to this file from `testEnvironment` in your jest config)

```
const JSDOMEnvironment = require('jest-environment-jsdom');

module.exports = class CustomizedJSDomEnvironment extends JSDOMEnvironment {
  constructor(config) {
    super(config);
    this.global.jsdom = this.dom;// here you can try playing with JSDOM configurations
  }

  teardown() {
    this.global.jsdom = null;
    return super.teardown();
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm having some non-react logic in the code, that does interact with the DOM directly (i.e. `document.getElementById(elementId)`). That's why the node needs to be appended to the DOM.

Currently I'm doing

`const app = document.createElement('div'); app.setAttribute('id', 'app'); document.body.appendChild(app);`

before doing the `mount`. It works. But I thought that there might be a more centralized place for that.

Comment: You can extend `JSDOMEnvironment`, I updated the answer with an example